# Only one video is playing simultaneously on Safari (Mac)

Tags: html, reactjs, video, webrtc, simple-peer

I used Simple Peer(WebRTC), ReactJS for my video call service. In the video call screen, I used 2 video tags(contact video and user video) for video playback. When the call gets started after a successful connection, only the contact video is getting played(1st video tag) and when the contact turns off their video user video is getting played(2nd video tag).

This only happens on Safari(I only tested on Mac). It works fine in other browsers(Google Chrome, Firefox).

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC depends a lot on browsers and Safari has specific requirements (like strict  order of tracks). Check JS console to identify any errors.
You can experiment with a [turnkey html5 videocall solution](https://github.com/videowhisper/VideoCall-HTML5-Videochat-PHP) that works and try to replicate.